# Jquery or operator issue

Tags: jquery, syntax

My code is;

`$('#selector1') || $('#selector2').on('click',function(){ //Your code here  });`

but || not working, just getting $('#selector2'), not $('#selector1').

Comment: A jQuery object is never falsy, it will always return a true value. What are you expecting the `||` operator to do here?

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want the click event handler be applied to both elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is correct the correct behavior.

The ".on" method allows you to add a listener on an object in the DOM. However, just like any method, it needs to be called on the object itself, just like you do in the selector2.

Now that we know that, what you actually want to do is put a listener on **both** selectors, not one **or** the other.

A clean way to do so would be to put your function outside of the on method and simply call the function for all the selectors on which you want to run this function once clicked.
This would be less obtrusive and more recommended!

This would look something like this :

```
const myFunction = function(){
    // your code here
}

$('#selector1, #selector2').on('click',myFunction);
```

Edit: Thanks to RoryMcCrossan, I updated the answer as he reminded me that jQuery has a clean way to select many items in the dom at once.